# Unity наглухо виснет без причины, открывается много окон

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Ни с того, ни с сего возникла такая проблема в `Unity(2021.3.15f1)`:

Во время работы в программе, без какой либо причины, через какое то время после запуска начинают открываться очень много окон, а юнити зависает и закрывать его приходится через диспетчер задач. Выглядит как краш программы, но юнька не вылетает, а именно зависает. Среди окон, которые появляются есть `Node.js` (я им никогда не пользовался), окно идёт с программы `Unity Package Manager.exe`,также открывается `Unity Shader Compiler.exe` если открыты другие программы типа браузеры, проводник, адобовские проги (в моём случае иллюстратор), то выскакивают окна вложенные в эти программы. Менял версию, переустанавливал, ничего не помогает. Гуглил - ни у кого такой проблемы не было. А самого эта ошибка очень бесит, т.к. сохранить сделанное нельзя из за того что юнити виснет. Причём конкретной причины почему это происходит нет, это происходит просто в рандомный момент работы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, проблема решается обновлением версии *Windows 11* до новой. Я использую *Windows 11 Insider Preview*, а она сырая, из за этого *Unity* крашится. Не уверен что ещё кто то столкнулся с этой проблемой, но если вдруг - нужно просто пересесть на стабильную версию *Windows*, или дождаться обновления.